# adding two stacks together

Tags: python-3.x, stack

I'm trying to write a function, `mrg_stacks(s1, s2)`, which merges two stacks together and returns a new stack. The two parameter stacks should remain with the same original values in order.

```
def mrg_stacks(s1,s2):
```

I have also created test cases:

```
stack_a = Stack()
stack_a.push(1)
stack_a.push(2)
stack_b = Stack()
stack_b.push(3)
stack_b.push(4)
my_stack = merge_stacks(stack_a , stack_b)
while not my_stack.is_empty():
  print( my_stack.pop())
while not stack_a.is_empty():
  print( stack_a.pop())
while not stack_b.is_empty():
  print( stack_b.pop())
```

Result:

```
4
3
2
1
2
1
4
3
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: merges two stacks together and returns a new stack.

Comment: so i can use things like  Stack(), push(), pop() and is_empty() where necessary inside the function

Answer (score 0):

you can use append and pop as synonymous to push and pop in python.

so you have

```
print "Hello World!\n"
def merge(a,b):
    ans = []
    while(len(a)>0):
        ans.append(a.pop())
    while(len(b)>0):
        ans.append(b.pop())
    return(ans)
a = [3,4]
b = [1,2]  
m = merge(a,b)
for k in m:
    print(k)
```

prints:

4
3
2
1

Comment: ill try running that with the test cases i have

Comment: If you have test cases you might as well post them with the question... Unless this is homework, in which case you should ask your teacher if you are allowed to post questions.

Comment: i did post them? their are the top

Comment: yeah thats the reason, any other suggestions

Comment: yeah use a stack not a list.

Comment: but stack can have the len() attribute ?

Comment: No that is a substitute. If it has to be a stack this has to be homework.

Comment: yeah it is, were allowed to post it

Comment: Ok if your teacher calls that a test case your teacher shouldn't be teaching. A test case is functional code that accepts a method as an argument and asserts true or false based on the methods performance.

Comment: haha wish i could tell them that, but unfortunately i have to finish this

Answer (score 0):

This is the same game every cs student since Turing has done.

```
class node():
    value = None
    next = None
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.value=val
    def setNext(self,next):
        self.next=next

class Stack:
    next = None
    current = None
    def is_empty(self):
        if(current == none):
            return(True)
        return(False)
    def push(self,next):
        next.setNext(self.current)
        self.current = next
    def pop(self):
        temp = self.current
        self.current = self.current.next
        return(temp)

def mrg_stacks(a,b):
    ans = []
    while(not a.is_empty):
        ans.append(a.pop())
    while(not b.is_empty):
        ans.append(b.pop())
    return(ans)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_empty - got this error

Comment: That's becasue you need to make and b stacks. If you cannot make it work from here you probably shouldn't get credit for the assignment.

Comment: I'll give you a hint tho -->  my mrg_stacks function returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

Lol compsci 105?
Try draw it out as a diagram first:
top--->bottom (stack)
Stack A: |2|1|
Stack B: |4|3|
Merged Stack: |4|3|2|1|
So you want to get from stack A & B to the Merged Stack via the push and pop methods but you can't do it directly as popping from Stack A and then pushing it would give it the incorrect order. So my hint: Invert the stacks